# Transpose mutiple columns in a Pyspark dataframe with a condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe that looks like this.

```
id cd1 version1   dt1   cd2 version2  dt2      cd3 version3    dt3
1  100    1    20100101 101    1     20100101  102            20100301        
1  101    1    20100102 102          20100201  100    1       20100302
2  201    1    20100103 100    1     20100301  100    1       20100303
2  202    2    20100104 100    1     20100105
```

I need to transpose all the codes into a single column with the following conditions

- If the corresponding version code is 1, add a decimal point after the first digit
- Each patient should have distinct codes

For the above example, the output should look like this.

```
id    code     dt
1     1.00   20100101
1     1.01   20100101
1     102    20100301
1     1.01   20100102
1     102    20100201
1     10.0   20100302
2     2.01   20100103
2     1.00   20100301
2     1.00   20100303
2     202    20100104
2     10.0   20100105
```

I am using Pyspark to do this. In the above example, I have shown only 3 codes with their corresponding version columns but I have 30 such columns. Also, this data has around 25 million rows.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode` a list of these columns so that there is only one `(cd, version)` pair per line

First, let's create the dataframe:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([[1,100,1,101,1,102,None],[1,101,1,102,None,100,1],[2,201,1,100,1,100,1],
                               [2,202,2,100,1,None,None]]).toDF(["id","cd1","version1","cd2","version2","cd3","version3"])
```

1. Using `posexplode`:

   ```py
   import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
   from itertools import chain
   nb_versions = 4
   df = df.na.fill(-1).select(
       "id", 
       psf.posexplode(psf.create_map(list(chain(*[(psf.col("cd" + str(i)), psf.col("version"+str(i))) for i in range(1, nb_versions)])))).alias("pos", "cd", "version")
   ).drop("pos").filter("cd != -1")

       +---+---+-------+
       | id| cd|version|
       +---+---+-------+
       |  1|100|      1|
       |  1|101|      1|
       |  1|102|     -1|
       |  1|101|      1|
       |  1|102|     -1|
       |  1|100|      1|
       |  2|201|      1|
       |  2|100|      1|
       |  2|100|      1|
       |  2|202|      2|
       |  2|100|      1|
       +---+---+-------+
   ```
2. Using `explode`:

   ```py
   nb_versions = 4
   df = df.select(
       "id", 
       psf.explode(psf.array(
           [psf.struct(
               psf.col("cd" + str(i)).alias("cd"), 
               psf.col("version" + str(i)).alias("version")) for i in range(1, nb_versions)])).alias("temp"))\
       .select("id", "temp.*")

       +---+----+-------+
       | id|  cd|version|
       +---+----+-------+
       |  1| 100|      1|
       |  1| 101|      1|
       |  1| 102|   null|
       |  1| 101|      1|
       |  1| 102|   null|
       |  1| 100|      1|
       |  2| 201|      1|
       |  2| 100|      1|
       |  2| 100|      1|
       |  2| 202|      2|
       |  2| 100|      1|
       |  2|null|   null|
       +---+----+-------+
   ```

Now we can implement your conditions

- division by 100 for version==1
- distinct values

We'll use functions `when, otherwise` for the condition and `distinct`:

```py
df.withColumn("cd", psf.when(df.version == 1, df.cd/100).otherwise(df.cd))\
    .distinct().drop("version")

    +---+-----+
    | id|   cd|
    +---+-----+
    |  1|  1.0|
    |  1| 1.01|
    |  1|102.0|
    |  2|  1.0|
    |  2| 2.01|
    |  2|202.0|
    +---+-----+
```

Comment: I tried this but I have null values in the cd field which gives me an error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use null as map key!"

Comment: It seems you wnat to filter them out anyways. If not you can use `na.fill` or change the method for `epxlode`

Comment: I agree I can just fill the null values with a random value and then filter them out.I realized I have a date field too.. I edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it. I am sure there is a better way to do this.

```
def process_code(raw_data):
    for i in range(1,4):
        cd_col_name = "cd" + str(i)
        version_col_name = "version" + str(i)
        raw_data = raw_data.withColumn("mod_cd" + str(i), when(raw_data[version_col_name] == 1, concat(substring(raw_data[cd_col_name],1,1),lit("."),substring(raw_data[cd_col_name],2,20))).otherwise(raw_data[cd_col_name]))

    mod_cols = [col for col in raw_data.columns if 'mod_cd' in col]
    nb_versions = 3
    new = raw_data.fillna('9999', subset=mod_cols).select("id", psf.posexplode(psf.create_map(list(chain(*[(psf.col("mod_cd" + str(i)), psf.col("dt"+str(i))) for i in range(1, nb_versions)])))).alias("pos", "final_cd", "final_date")).drop("pos")
    return new

test = process_code(df)
test = test.filter(test.final_cd != '9999')
test.show(100, False)
```